Movie based on real events about a transgender woman who was murdered
I saw this movie last night on TV, but not the whole thing and I didn't see the name.
It was about the life and troubles of a trans woman that at the age of 17 (?) was murdered by some teenage boys that tried to get intimate with her and found out she was a man.
The movie showed the life of the aforementioned girl in flashbacks and also the trial of her murderers in parallel.
It must have been set in the late 90's or early 2000's and it must have been filmed a little later than that.
Also, I was told that it was based on a true story. 

Sounds like A Girl Like Me: The Gwen Araujo Story:

The story documents the real life of Gwen Araujo, born Edward Araujo, Jr., a transgender teenager who was murdered after she was discovered by acquaintances that she had male genitalia. Scenes depicting the murder trial are shown alternating with the story of Gwen's life.

She was murdered in 2002 and the movie is from 2006. Here are some clips from it:



